# Issue with importing cicd workflow to another repo

Tags: github, github-actions, custom-error-pages

Recently I imported a repo (which has github actions) from one account to another private account on github.

In the new account, I tried to View Run, I get a 404 error.

Did I miss something that I needed to do during the importing process?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after googling for 30min.

You have to enable `Allow all actions and reusable workflows` from the specific repo you want Actions enabled.

[repo] > Settings > Actions > General > Allow all actions and reusable workflows